# Excel VBA selecting cells from filtered range

Tags: vba, excel

The code below is part of a larger form. What I'm trying to do is:

- On sheet 2 (Data List) filter data based on column 1
- Based on user selected items in a listbox pull out data from the filtered range from columns 2 and 3 for specific rows and paste into sheet 1 (JHA)
- I know which rows the data is in only within the filtered list because I'm storing it in a 2D array dataArr

  ```
  Sheets("Data List").Select

  With Worksheets("Data List").Range("A1", Sheets("Data List").Range("C1").End(xlDown)) 
  .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=UserForm1.ListBox3.List(k) 'filter data based on user listbox selection
  For j = 0 To UserForm1.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 'Find user selection from LB3 in LB1 to match filtered data order
      If UserForm1.ListBox3.List(k) = UserForm1.ListBox1.List(j) Then Exit For
  Next j   
  For h = 0 To UBound(dataArr, 2)
      If dataArr(j, h) = 1 Then 'If the user has selected they want this data then add it to the array

      Set myRange = Sheets("Data List").AutoFilter.Range().SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      myRange.Select
      arr1(l) = myRange.Cells(h + 2, 2) 
      arr2(l) = myRange.Cells(h + 2, 3)
      l = l + 1
  End If
  Next h
  .AutoFilter
  ```

  After this bit of code I redimension the array and paste the data on the other sheet. My issue is that myRange.cells is selecting from the unfiltered data. So for example say my filtered data set includes rows 7, 11, 15 and 21. When I filter it and set myRange it highlights 4 rows plus the header. However, when I use cells(2, 2) I get the unfiltered row 2 column 2 data, not for my filtered data set. I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I can't see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Filtered range can be (well, it almost always is!) a not contiguous one, so you have to iterate through it and pitch the nth value

You may want to use this function:

```
Function GetFilteredCellsNthValue(filteredRng As Range, nthVal As Long) As Variant
    Dim iVal As Long, Dim cell As Range

     iVal = 1
    ForEach cell in filteredRng
        If iVal = nthVal Then Exit For
        iVal = iVal + 1
    Next
    GetFilteredCellsNthValue = Iif(iVal>filteredRng.Count, CVErr(xlErrValue), cell.Value)
End Function
```

That could be used in your "main" code as follows

```
arr1(l) = GetFilteredCellsNthValue( .Resize(,1).Offset(.Rows.Count - 1,1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)), h + 2)

arr2(l) = GetFilteredCellsNthValue( .Resize(,1).Offset(.Rows.Count - 1,2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)), h + 2)
```

Comment: @mylesMoose, did you get through it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Pretty neat way of going through it. I hadn't about the filtered range not being contiguous.